# How can know about a series if $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_j < \infty $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose
$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_j < \infty $$

Can I say this series $\Sigma a_j$ is convergent? I only know the definition of the series convergent is that if the partial sum sequence is convergent. I also know if the series $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_j$ converges, then we have $\lim_{j \to \infty} a_j=0$.

I just don't know how to interpret $\Sigma a_j$. What is the meaning of $$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_j < \infty $$ I know it means $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_j$ is finite, of course.

Comment: $\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty a_j=\lim\limits_{N\to \infty}\sum\limits_{j=1}^N a_j$ by definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the equation

$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j<\infty$$

means that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{j=1}^n a_j=L$$

That is, the partial sums converge to a finite limit. However, this is a slightly sloppy notation as it would be just as valid to assume that it implies

$$\left|\sum_{j=1}^n a_j\right|<M$$

for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (for example $a_j=(-1)^j$). Context will usually tell you which of these the notation refers to (or any other natural definitions you might be able to think of).

Comment: Why it could imply $\left|\sum_{j=1}^n a_j\right|<M$?

Comment: It just means that the notation is sloppy as different people might read it as different things.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ n_0\in \Bbb N $ and $ (a_n)_{n\ge n_0} $ be a real sequence.

For $ n\ge n_0 $,

$$S_n=\sum_{j=n_0}^na_j$$

If $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}S_n=L\in \Bbb R$$
then
the series $ \sum_{n\ge n_0}a_n $ is convergent and its limit $ L $ is said to be its sum. We write
$$\sum_{j=n_0}^{+\infty}a_j=L<+\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

You said it, it means that the sequence of partial sums, $s_k: =\sum_{j=1}^ka_j $ converges.
So it relies on the notion of *sequence* convergence.